# Java jsonpath lost dot in the expression

Tags: java, json, jsonpath

I have an issue. When JSONPATH v 2.8.0 created an expression from parameter expression I lost a dot.

Example of JSON:

```
{
    "el1": [
    {"attr": "value1"},
    {"attr": "value2"}
    ],
    "el2": false
}
```

My code:

```
JsonPath.read(JSON, "$..el1.attr"));
```

But somehow jsonpath turn it into:

```
 $..['el1']['attr']
```

And it should be:

```
$..['el1'].['attr']
```

But I don't know why it isn't.